# Подзапрос возращает несколько колонок

Tags: mysql, sql

Привет.Как поступить если подзапрос возвращает несколько колонок.
Знаю вариант через создание временных таблиц,но хочется услышать другое решение.Припустим

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM имя WHERE `колонка_1` IN ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS `so`,`колонка_1` FROM `имя` GROUP BY `колонка_1` ORDER BY `so` DESC ))";
```

есть специальный оператор?Хочу с подзапроса вытащит только колонку `колонка_1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно запустить подзапрос еще раз, уже без условий:

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM имя WHERE `колонка_1` IN (select `колонка_1` from (SELECT COUNT(*) AS `so`,`колонка_1` FROM `имя` GROUP BY `колонка_1` OR.....
```

Отработает он достаточно быстро.

Comment: ну раз достаточно быстро то нормально.Слышал есть оператор "NOT EXISTS" думал его сдесь можно было применить...

Answer (score 1):

Через оператор "EXISTS" будет что-то вроде:

```
$sql1="SELECT * FROM таблица1 WHERE EXISTS ((SELECT COUNT(*) AS `so`,`колонка_1` FROM таблица2 WHERE таблица2.`колонка_1` = таблица1.`колонка_1` GROUP BY `колонка_1` ORDER BY `so` DESC ))";
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Не вполне понятно, каково назначение этого запроса без предложения LIMIT в подзапросе.
2. Если я правильно понял замысел, то короче будет так:

   $sql1="SELECT * FROM имя NATURAL JOIN (SELECT `колонка_1` FROM `имя` GROUP BY `колонка_1` ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC LIMIT 1) X";